# Merge 5 Vectors To Matrix C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm using C++.
I have 5 vectors.

```
int currDim = 5;
int a[currDim] = {1,6,11,16,21};
int b[currDim] = {2,7,12,17,22};
int c[currDim] = {3,8,13,18,23};
int d[currDim] = {4,9,14,19,24};
int e[currDim] = {5,10,15,20,25};
```

I want to merge them to one `int matrix[currDim][5].`
The matrix should be:

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
{6,7,8,9,10}
{11,12,13,14,15}
{16,17,18,19,20}
{21,22,23,24,25}
```

What i'm did:

```
int j=k=0;
for(int i = 0; i<currDim ; i++)
{
     matrix[i][k++] = a[j];
     matrix[i][k++] = b[j];
     matrix[i][k++] = c[j];
     matrix[i][k++] = d[j];
     matrix[i][k++] = e[j];
     k = 0;
     j++;
}
```

The code is works but i looking for better way to increased efficiency , any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I may have to apologize for my answer may not help, since I'm not quite sure what you mean by asking for "**better ways**": It could mean **better coding style**, **increased efficiency**, or **generality**.

Since it is really a simple task that only takes 25 assignment operations you are dealing with, efficiency is not such a big issue here.

However, for the elegance's sake, you can consider using an **array of pointers** to store a,b,c,d,e and replace five excessive assignment statements with a simple, elegant loop, just like the following code shows:

```
typedef int *pInt;
//Each element of arr is a int-type pointer
pInt arr[5] = {a, b, c, d, e};

int matrix[5][5] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5; ++j){
        matrix[i][j] = arr[j][i];
    }
}
```

Let me know if my approach is helpful to you.

P.S. I usually leave left bracket in the end rather than starting a new line, and I tend to use `++i` instead of `i++`, it's more of a personal habit and you don't need to exactly follow my style.